# Instagram Call API Login

Tags: php, oauth, instagram-api

I try to call the API to log in. This afternoon everything was ok, but since two hours i received this error...I don't understand because i get the code parameter... (As you can see under this sentence)

```
InstagramService.php on line 78:
"ff6229d27c******6b0aada76a98*****b5d"

InstagramService.php on line 79:
{#578 ▼
  +"code": 400
  +"error_type": "OAuthException"
  +"error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."
}
```

If someone could help me it will be appreciated...

Regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have the answer. It's a cookie generated by Instagram which block the request after a first successful call.